# Flask JSON not working: BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to pass user input into flask python file using JSON..
this is the citizins input element in the html body:

```
<form class="networkform" method="POST">
<input name="citizens" maxlength="15" class="InputStyle" required>
<button type="submit" style="height: 40px; width: 180px; background-color: grey; color:white">send</button>
</form>
```

this is the jQuery function in the html file:

```
$(".networkform").on('submit', function(e){
                alert("submit is working")

                $.ajax({
                    data :
                    {
                       'citizens' : $("citizens").val(),
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : '/Dash'
                })
                .done(function(data){
                        $(".outerDiv").hide()


                })

                e.preventDefault();
        });
```

and this is the function in the .py file:

```
@app.route('/Dash', methods=['POST'])
def Dash():
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("inside post")
    num_citizins = request.form['citizens']
    print(num_citizins)
    return jsonify({"msg" : "Thanks"})
```

and here is the main in .py file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print 'Start'
  main()
  app.run(debug=True)
  print 'Done!'
```

But for some reason it's not working at all.. here is the error I get:

```
BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

KeyError: 'citizens'

solutions I already tried:

- used app.run(debug=True, threaded=True) instead of app.run(debug=True) in main
- used request.form.get instead of request.form
- removed method="post" from 
  but nothing works.. each time it gives a different type of errors.. what do you think the problem could be? (if any of those matter; I'm using python 2.7, IDE: pyCharm, Browser: Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Dash()` function, change the following line

```py
num_citizins = request.form['citizens']
```

to

```py
num_citizins = request.json['citizens']
```

You are sending JSON data which is received in `request.json`. You also need to set the request content type to `application/json` for the `.json` property to work.

### Edit

Here's how content type will be set in jQuery. You just need to add `contentType : 'application/json'` like this:

```
                $.ajax({
                    data :
                    {
                       'citizens' : $("citizens").val(),
                    },
                    type : 'POST',
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    url : '/Dash'
                })
```

Comment: I changed request.form into request.json , but sorry can you explain more where to put application/json?

Comment: @HeilaAl-Mogren I have edited the answer and attached the snippet